# Crystal Reports not firing

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

HTML Code

```
 <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
```

.cs code

```
EmployeeDBBroker EDB = new EmployeeDBBroker();
DataSet ds = EDB.GetListofemployeebyCategory(Convert.ToInt32(department),Convert.ToInt32(category));
lbCollegeName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DName"].ToString();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
   dt = ds.Tables[0];
   ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
   crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("Cry_ListofEmployee.rpt"));
   Student dsCustomers = GetData();
   crystalReport.SetDataSource(ds);

   CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
   CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: _not firing_ what you mean? Have you exception? add also your web.config

Comment: Thanks Steve. Not Firing Means Not Displaying Window . And web.Config

Comment: Try to remove the Autodatabind=true and then replace the line `CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()` by this : `CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind()`